# Mark a Python class as abstract by hand for Doxygen

Tags: python, doxygen

I'm using Doxygen to generate a documentation for a Python project.

I want to mark a certain Python 2 class as *abstract*, is there any default way to get Doxygen to do this for me (some command like *@abstract* in the class docstring), or do I have to create a regular remark?

Comment: Do you mean an actual [`abc`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm not actually using abc, I just want to inform users of the library that the class may only be used by subclassing.